# No me salen todas las filas al hacer una consulta MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql, group-by

al ejecutar el query solo me sale una fila, pero tendrian que aperecer dos mas

```
 SELECT empleat.codi_empleat,nom, total,  
           SUM(total) AS TotalComandes
    FROM empleat, comandes
    WHERE empleat.codi_empleat=comandes.codi_empleat;
```

Ayuda porfavor

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y porque, si no hay un group by...

Comment: Si nos muestras las tablas de las que consultas y, ojalá, algunos datos de prueba junto con el resultado deseado, podríamos ayudarte. Cualquier consulta es correcta dependiendo de lo que se desee

Comment: Mete al final un `group by` de todas las columnas de tu `SELECT` menos la que esta como argumento de la función de agregación `SUM`